# how to highlight key word in angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

i am using angular material and i have a searched keyword. so i need to highlight searched keyword which comes dynamically in the table.i tried with innerHTML but it didnt work.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5m6rnk-2cxxp4?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-flex-basic-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftable-flex-basic-example.ts)

HTML:

```
<h2>Searched word: UM</h2>
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pipe in order to hightlight key in your innerHTML.

Create a pipe "highlight"

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'highlight'
})

export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args: any): any {
        if (!args) {return value;}
        var re = new RegExp(args, 'gi'); //'gi' for case insensitive and can use 'g' if you want the search to be case sensitive.
        return value.replace(re, "<mark>$&</mark>");
    }
}
```

Use innerhtml (you can replace UM with your searched key)

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [innerHTML]="element.name  | highlight : 'UM'">  </mat-cell>
```

[Updated Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5m6rnk-fq4xv2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhighlight.pipe.ts)

Comment: thanks for response, instead of background as yellow, i just want to highlight 'UM' in bold.

Comment: @Bhrungarajni replace "mark" tag with "b", I've updated the demo

Comment: any idea, about how to use angular material sorting based on column click

Answer (score 1):

Here I'm adding an additional property called isHighlighted and use ngClass to display different styles.

```js
    export class TableFlexBasicExample{
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name'];
      dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

      ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = this.dataSource.map((obj) => {
          if (obj.name.includes('um')) {
            return { ...obj, isHighlighted: true };
          }
          return { ...obj, isHighlighted: false };
        });
      }
    }
```

```css
    .highlight::after {
      content: 'um';
      color: red; 
    }
```

```html
 <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell
          *matCellDef="let element"
          [ngClass]="{'highlight' : element.isHighlighted}"
        >
          {{element.name}}
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
```

Comment: You should use `NgClass` or `NgStyle` instead of `NgIf`.

Comment: edited it to use NgClass :)

Comment: thanks for response, but i need only those characters to be highlighted not the full name, pls suggest